# Is it okay to do repository calls from adapters

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask, android-adapter

Suppose I have an adapter that renders a listView. It needs data from a database to load some text. Is it okay to do a database call from a UI thread?

Is there a way I can get data from a db in the background(asynchronously) without making calls to the database on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best practice is to load data asynchronously you use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or if possible you can use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: How do I get the data from the loader to my adapter??

Comment: if you follow android guidelines you should get your data in `onCreateLoader()` method and in `onLoadFinished()` method you load data from `cursor` to your adapter